# How to clear browser cache with php?

Tags: php, browser, caching

How to clear browser cache with php?

Comment: You mean: How to prevent my stuff from being cached. You can´t *clear* a browsers cache from the server without preinstalled software (activeX etc.) that has extensive rights to modify the user´s system.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Clearing the cache everytime isn't always the best option though. It might be worth reading up on.

Comment: Content-Type here is a red herring.

Comment: this doesn't clear the user's browser cache. It does tell the browser to not cache this particular page, however.

Comment: A good way for not having to teach your client how to clear cache.

Comment: this code is not working for me sir...   i have to reload manually my page.

Comment: This will prevent future caching of the affected resource, but till not clear existing caches.

Answer (score 41):

You can delete the browser cache by setting these headers:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: This works for me. I tried to make a preview of a 6MB pdf. My script working for small sized pdfs but not more than 3 mbs.

Comment: This is the way how to clear cache including loaded audio or image file path.

Comment: This won't clear a cache that's already there. If the browser has visited the page previously and the headers were set to cache, it will most likely just load the cached files and never receive the new no-cache headers until the user manually refreshes the content on their end.

Answer (score 4):

With recent browser support of "Clear-Site-Data" headers, you can clear different types of data:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data

header('Clear-Site-Data: "cache", "cookies", "storage", "executionContexts"');

Answer (score 1):

It seams you need to versionate, so when some change happens browser will catch something new and user won't need to clear browser's cache.

You can do it by subfolders `(example /css/v1/style.css)` or by filename `(example: css/style_v1.css)` or even by setting different folders for your website, example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/site1

www.mywebsite.com/site2

www.mywebsite.com/site3
```

And use a .htaccess or even change httpd.conf to redirect to your current application.

If's about **one** image or **page**:

```
    <?$time = date("H:i:s");?>
    <img src="myfile.jpg?time=<?$time;?>">
```

You can use $time on parts when you don't wanna cache. So it will always pull a new image. Versionate it seams a better approach, otherwise it can overload your server. Remember, browser's cache it's not only good to user experience, but also for your server.

Comment: The only problem is, if the browser keeps just loading the page from cache, it isn't sending a request to the server and it ain't gonna matter what you do on the server.  But yes, this will work if say the page is reloading, but resources aren't, which I often find the case even when force-refreshing a browser manually (eg, shift + refresh).  Chrome seems to be the worst and I've pulled my hair out trying to satisfy clients who use Chrome.

Comment: This will print `myfile.jpg?time=` because you are not printing $time.  You need: <img src="myfile.jpg?time=<?print $time;?>">