# Session destroy

Tags: php, session

In my working platform i endedup with a session_destroy problem

```
function logout()
{

 $_SESSION['id'] = '';
 session_destroy();

}
```

Here i unset the session id variable with a null value and uses the session_destroy() function to destroy the session.

But the problem is that after logged out from my account, when i press the **back button** of the browser it shows the status as **logged in**. **Even i can browse through the profile and links of my account**.

Thank you

Comment: The manual on `session_destroy()` shows how to completely destroy a session (although yours may be rather a caching problem)

Comment: try to use `$_SESSION = array();` instead of the `$_SESSION['id'] = '';`

Comment: May be this thread will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php

Answer (score 4):

you must unset session as well as destroy session to remove it completely from your system.

you can do it with php functions..

```
session_unset(); or you can use unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use unset($_SESSION) - the PHP manual explicitly says not to.

Comment: Caution: Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 2):

it think you should try using [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset.
>
> If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) may be used for that

```
<?php
session_start();

$sessionName = session_name();
$sessionCookie = session_get_cookie_params();

session_unset();
session_destroy();

setcookie($sessionName, false, $sessionCookie['lifetime'], $sessionCookie['path'],    $sessionCookie['domain'], $sessionCookie['secure']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id();
```

Comment: Caution: Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own session code and possibly missing something, try using Zend_Session:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.html

The constructor of Zend_Session_Namespace will automatically call session_start(), and likewise the Zend_Session::destroy() method will clean everything up in a logout script. Most of the work has already been done for you.