# redirect, force browser re cache?

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I just uploaded a new site to `www.mydomain.com`. The old site had an immediate redirect to `www.mydomain/cart/index.php`.

The problem is that my new site also has a cart folder. It seems that browsers are automatically redirecting to `/cart` even though I do not have this redirect setup anymore.

How can I force browsers to either recache or update their cached redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your URL is `http:/www.mydomain.com?a=b&c=d` 
you redirect to `http:/www.mydomain.com?a=b&c=d&nocache=1234567890` with `1234567890` being a large random number.  The browser should interpret this as a new request.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in htaccess? I don;t want to mess up any urls on my site that already use a querystring. Alternatively, how long before a browser does a proper re-cache?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution using php is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php).

If you need to clear it using HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Refer [here](http://fatherofcents.com/clear-browser-cache-using-html-or-php/).