# php website gives 403 unless i refresh my browser cache

Tags: php

I have a website that is on a live domain. Some times it loads okay but sometimes it gives me 403 forbidden, even for other users it does the same, i tried my every best to check permissions and every other stuff, but yesterday i just cleaned my browser cache and history etc, and bamm, website start working, then i realized its cache problem, What could be the solution to this problem, when i clean my cache my domain starts working, even c panel won't load until i clean my cache. Is it something about .htaccess, my .htaccess has only Options -Indexes and i removed that too to confirm myself if this was the problem .. but no luck.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php  also this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php for phd session read this http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But it does not work for me still .. i ve used the cache code from php but still no luck .. dont know whats the problem

Comment: You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

It should be your test machine problem.

Try it on any other machine.

Comment: Thanks your answer but no its not on a test machine, its on a server, the amazing things the same website on another server does not need to clear user browser cache. I ve did everything i could no matter i change chmods, htaccess is empty, may be its something with cookies and server.. when i clear cookies etc it start working

Comment: I meant to say: try accessing the website from a different machine