# Remove Template cache on logout Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, caching, browser-cache, back

How to remove Angular template cache once user clicks on logout? We did thorough research and tried to implement most of the solutions available out there. we tried following

**HTML Meta Tags**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

**Server side**

```
res.setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache', 'no-store', 'must-revalidate');
```

**Javascript**

We tried to delete browser history as specified on this [blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout.aspx)

Problem we are facing right now is when a user logs out from our app and press back button he is shown empty html templates as services are not cached how shall we make sure templates are not cached either?

Comment: just a suggesstion: manage back button to redirect user to login, rather than removing the template cache

Comment: Hi @HarishR How can we do that? Any link would be really helpful ..

Comment: you must be using some routing mechanism in your application either ui-router or ng-route, using that you can change the route on $routeChangeStart or $stateChangeStart

Comment: Thing is our login page is not made using angularJS. We have 1 common login page for multiple apps.

Comment: if that is managed at server side it would be much easier to do.

Comment: @entre We solved that issue by redirecting user to login page as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: great.. glad i helped... i will put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 14):

`$templateCache` is just a wrapper around `$cacheFactory` with a specific name. This is literally all of its code:

```
function $TemplateCacheProvider() {
  this.$get = ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('templates');
  }];
}
```

`$cacheFactory` has a `removeAll()` method. Try this, if you want to wire it up yourself (e.g. in a service into which you've injected `$cacheFactory`):

```
$cacheFactory('templates').removeAll();
```

But separately, maybe you want to disable caching entirely if your application is security-sensitive. You can do a reload() call on the entire browser to dump all local JS variables, and then your no-cache pragmas above on the actual HTTP-driven assets will do what you want.

Comment: IMO `$templateCache.removeAll()` looks better

Comment: Careful when using `$templateCache.removeAll()`. This actually removes everything, including templates used by third party libraries (like bootstrap-ui). Instead I suggest you remove templates individually using  `$templateCache.remove('template.html')`

Comment: $templateCache.removeAll() will break angularjs-toaster

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that resolve my problem, usign php, here [How to clear browser cache with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php)

I think you can set a http request to a file php using this headers:
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

In my case, all my app is on Angularjs but I connect to an api with php, so in that php I put the headers and it worked!

Hope you help!

Edit: 
My problem was on movile browser(IE edge of WindowsPhone10), and no more problems with this solution.

Comment: Answers should always be in the same language used in the question.