# Angular: Remove a specific template from cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I know how to remove all templates from cache by

```
$templateCache.removeAll();
```

But I want to remove a specific template only from cache. 
The template is not loaded from `$routeProvider` but it is being rendered from a directive by using

```
templateUrl: 'template/page/file.html'
```

My app structure is as this

```
-web
  - js
    - controllers
       - appController.js
  - templates
    - page
      - file.html
```

I did `$templateCache.remove('/templates/page/file.html');` in appController.js

Comment: have you tried to do something like $templateCache.remove('template/file.html') .... i think it is a common cache sistem and it use then path and name of a view as the key

Comment: yes i did try that, but its not working for me

Comment: `remove(key)` should work.

Comment: @tasseKATT what to write in `key`. can you show with an example?

Comment: The first answer tells that $templateCache use in fact $cacheFactory
Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267962/remove-template-cache-on-logout-angular-js
Try this: $cacheFactory.Cache.remove('yourTemplate')
Info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) is based off the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) and since the latter has a .remove(key), it will work on your $templateCache as well. Perhaps you got the wrong key?

You could try and call `.get(key)` to check if you do have the correct key (i suspect you don't - and that is the reason `.remove(key)` doesn't work for you).

Perhaps the path to your template file is messing up the key, a relative path might not be the actual key, but rather the full path or the filename alone.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you tell me what path to give in the key?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this in your run method of the app :

```
 app.run([
        "$rootScope", "$templateCache", "authService", function($rootScope, $templateCache, authService) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

                    if (typeof (current) !== "undefined") {
                        $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
                    }


            });
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: There is no $routeChange happening. I mentioned that in the question. It is being loaded from the directive.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with my code, the function trigger was not right. I solved it by

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $templateCache.remove('templates/page/file.html');
});
```

so now the template is removed from the cache when the page is loaded.
Thanks for all the help.