# Clear Brower Cache when logout

Tags: php, caching, browser

When I click logout user is redirected to home page and all session values are destroyed but when i click browser back button it still showing page as user is logged in.
So is there a way i can remove browser cache in php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php

Comment: check `session_id()` as  returns the string identifying the current session, if set then display that page else redirect him to index page