# Why are unlink and move_uploaded_file not working?

Tags: php

**Scenario**

I have a file uploader where I can upload files. There is another option to update the previously uploaded file. Also I can view the uploaded file using some link.

**Requirement**

Everything was working fine. Lets say I uploaded fileA. I can view this file using a link. Then I updated that file with another file named fileB. I can view this file using the same link. The issue here is, if I used same file name to upload second time, it will have error. Thus I modified my code the following way.

```
if(file_exists($target_fileCadEdit)){
    unlink($target_fileCadEdit);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCadEdit);
}else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCadEdit);
}
```

**Problem**

The old file is deleted and updating with the new file (Take note same file name for old and new file) correctly in the same location. But when I use the same link to view the updated file, it is still showing old file. I physically checked the uploaded file and the old file was not there anymore and updated with the new file. But still when I click view using the link, it is showing old file. Not sure from where program is accessing that deleted file.

Can anyone help?

**Edit**

Found out issue is due to browser cache. I tried to manually remove browser cache and tried again to view file and now it is showing the actual file present in the server.

**Problem Now**

Now the problem is, how to clear cache automatically while running script. Some suggestion is to try around with header tags. But I am afraid, it may affect performance if I configured wrongly. So I used another method `clearstatcache();`. But it seems not working too. Please see my code now

```
if(file_exists($target_fileCadEdit)){
    unlink($target_fileCadEdit);
    clearstatcache();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCadEdit);
    clearstatcache();
}else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCadEdit);
}
```

Here is my link to view the file. It is using many dynamic variables

```html
<td class="viewEditTd">
  <a href="<?php echo $locationForViewLink; ?><?php echo $slash; ?><?php echo $_POST['searchInput']; ?><?php echo $cadguiFolder; ?><?php echo $row['cadRevision']; ?><?php echo $slash; ?><?php echo $row['cadFile']; ?>" target="_blank" class="whiteLink"><span class="
        glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> View </a>
</td>
```

Any clue anyone?

Comment: Browser cache. There are two solutions.
1. change url sufix (url/your-image.jpg?4626)
2. config headers: Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by change url suffix. May I know what suffix you are referring to? i saw you added .jpg with some get variable as suffix. For the second method, if i do cache control, will it has any problem running other functions of the site? My website is for some file uploading, viewing, login system, file management etc

Comment: There is no way to delete browser cache of a single file.No you cannot physically delete cached file. Instead you can generate link to the file dynamically, for example file_url?some_random_str

Comment: @WaqarUlAziz I read some article about clearstatcache();. It is telling that able to clear cache using that command. I am struggling with that too. By the way I am interested to know more about generating link to the file dynamically with those random string at the back. Could you give some example how to do it? I updated my question by including the link to view the file. Could you refer to that and help?

Comment: clearstatcache() is used to clear clear cache on server not on browser, it is nothing to do in your scenario.

Comment: @WaqarUlAziz Thank you for directing me the right direction. I am able to solve the issue

Comment: @WaqarUlAziz Seems like it is possible to clear browser cache. You may read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php)

Comment: yes but it is for php or html files. For static resources e.g. image, stylesheet or javascript cache can not be cleared without adding some query string.

Comment: @WaqarUlAziz Okay. Seems like I need to learn more about cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on suggestions from Stack over flow members, I am able to solve the issue by making the file opening link url dynamic and thus link always point to different file name. 
Here is my final working code

**File unlinking and uploading block**

```
if(file_exists($target_fileCadEdit)){
    unlink($target_fileCadEdit);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCadEdit);
}else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCadEdit);
}
```

**File viewing block**

```
<td class="viewEditTd">
    <a href="<?php echo $locationForViewLink; ?><?php echo $slash; ?><?php echo $_POST['searchInput']; ?><?php echo $cadguiFolder; ?><?php echo $row['cadRevision']; ?><?php echo $slash; ?><?php echo $row['cadFile'].'?'; ?><?php echo generateRandomString(); ?>" target="_blank" class="whiteLink"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> View </a>
</td>
```

Take note about the part where after file name, I gave `?` and then `echo` the function `generateRandomString()`

**Function to generate Random String**

Thanks to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)  for codes to generate random numbers

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```