# How tu run laravel php artisan serve with fresh cache

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-artisan

I am using `php artisan serve` to start my mini app on my remote server.

Once I update code, I am using ftp to upload new code.

After upload I am stop and restart (`php artisan serve`), but view are still "old", there is something like cache, how can I clear it?

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan config:clear` then clear the view `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Doesnt work, still it same

Comment: What's you have cahnged in your app?

Comment: I changed vue js files

Comment: Then its may be cached by your CDN. If so, then you need to be waited or purge the cache from your CDN

Comment: Do you mean my provider CDN or sometinh like this ? I dont have any cdn I just have cloudflare free version.

Comment: If you are using cloudflare,  then you are using [tag:CloudFlare] CDN too (including free version). Go to your CloudFlare panel, select your site and go to `Caching` -> `Configuration` then `Purge Everything`. It will purge your all current cache files, now clear cache from your browser and access your site. If you don't want to purge manually.  Then you need to be waited some hour (max 24 hour)

Answer (score 1):

try  `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

If You want to clear file cache then you can use `clearstatcache()`.If you are checking a file several times in a script, to avoid caching & to get correct results, use the `clearstatcache()` function. see more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

But if you want clear browser cache then you can delete it using headers.
see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php)